# How can I use Cauchy formula to this Integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$∫ \frac{5z^2 - 3z + 2}{(z-1)^3} dz$$

and the contour is any closed simple curve involving z=1 (sorry, I forgot to write this information)

Need to solve it using Cauchy Integral formula

Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the contour of this integral?

Comment: I edited the question, I really forgot to mention about the contour...sorry.

Comment: Quite all right, Sabrina. Should we assume that we're to integrate in the counterclockwise/anticlockwise/positively-oriented direction?

Comment: My examples in the book is using anticlock wise

Answer (score 1):

You can consider your cantour as a circle
centered at one with radius $r$. Then the integral equals

> $$\int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{(z-1)^3}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{2!} f^{(2)}(1)$$

**Note:**

> **Theorem 1:** If $f(z)$ is analytic inside and on the boundary $C$ of a simply-connected region $R$ and $a$ is any point inside $C$ then
>
> $$ f(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz. $$

Comment: Of course, if the singularity is *not* located within the countour, or if the contour winds around the singularity multiple times, or in the other direction, this doesn't work. Basically, tetori's question is super important.

Comment: I thought that since the contour is any closed simple curve involving z=1 I can assume |z|=1, which means I may have a circle centred in (0,0) with r = 1. Is wrong to assume this?

Comment: @CameronBuie: First, when he posted his question he did not specify the contour, so I assumed the contour to be as in the answer which turned out to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Youre asked to find $\int_{\vert z \vert = 1}\frac{5z^2-3z+2}{(z-1)^3}dz$. Here, for Cauchy integral formula, $n=2$, so you have

$$2\pi i \bigg(\frac{d^2}{dz^2}5z^2-3z+2 \bigg\vert_{z=1}\bigg)=2\pi i (10)=20\pi i.$$